# Python issue with installing scikit-learn In pycharm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

so I'm having an issue with installing scikit-learn in Pycharm. Here's the error code

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.2.2.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
        Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [40 lines of output]
            The Meson build system
            Version: 1.1.1
            Source dir: /private/var/folders/c5/7bp39l255q5c7bf9j_8t2s8c0000gn/T/pip-install-sju6xn7_/scipy_bcf1716e49654d2db8011d8ebda0da5f
            Build dir: /private/var/folders/c5/7bp39l255q5c7bf9j_8t2s8c0000gn/T/pip-install-sju6xn7_/scipy_bcf1716e49654d2db8011d8ebda0da5f/.mesonpy-jflrrsl0/build
            Build type: native build
            Project name: SciPy
            Project version: 1.10.1
            C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)")
            C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 650.9
            C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)")
            C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 650.9
            Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.35)
            Host machine cpu family: aarch64
            Host machine cpu: aarch64
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
            Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: YES
            Library m found: YES
      
            ../../meson.build:63:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['ifx'], ['g95']]
            The following exception(s) were encountered:
            Running `gfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
            Running `gfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
            Running `flang --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
            Running `flang -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
            Running `nvfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
            Running `nvfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
            Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
            Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
            Running `ifort --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
            Running `ifort -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
            Running `ifx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
            Running `ifx -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
            Running `g95 --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
            Running `g95 -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      
            A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/c5/7bp39l255q5c7bf9j_8t2s8c0000gn/T/pip-install-sju6xn7_/scipy_bcf1716e49654d2db8011d8ebda0da5f/.mesonpy-jflrrsl0/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
            + meson setup --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11 /private/var/folders/c5/7bp39l255q5c7bf9j_8t2s8c0000gn/T/pip-install-sju6xn7_/scipy_bcf1716e49654d2db8011d8ebda0da5f /private/var/folders/c5/7bp39l255q5c7bf9j_8t2s8c0000gn/T/pip-install-sju6xn7_/scipy_bcf1716e49654d2db8011d8ebda0da5f/.mesonpy-jflrrsl0/build --native-file=/private/var/folders/c5/7bp39l255q5c7bf9j_8t2s8c0000gn/T/pip-install-sju6xn7_/scipy_bcf1716e49654d2db8011d8ebda0da5f/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
      
      × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I've walked through a lot of different steps of installing it in bash/terminal but nothing seems to be working. I used brew, and a lot of different code in the terminal I found online, any help would be appreciated! Everything just leads to an error. I've tried to manually install it through pycharm as well, still does not work

Comment: See: https://discuss.python.org/t/unable-to-install-scikit-learn/26495/8 and linked https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#installing-on-apple-silicon-m1-hardware. *"At the time of writing (January 2021), the only way to get a working installation of scikit-learn on this hardware is to install scikit-learn and its dependencies from the conda-forge distribution, for instance using the miniforge installers"*

Comment: Although someone here suggests using `pip3 install -U --no-use-pep517 scikit-learn` https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19137#issuecomment-1027551696

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I created a virtual environment and tried to install packages from a requirements.txt file that included the scikit-learn library.If you haven't found a solution yet, you can check out [the link](https://discuss.python.org/t/unable-to-install-scikit-learn/26495/9) which contains a hot discussion on the topic. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34782905)